# Quando apago o último caracter do EditText o app PARA, o que fazer?

Tags: android, edittext

Eu digito uma sequencia de número normalmente e talz, agora se por exemplo eu digito "1234" em qualquer um dos 3 **EditTexts** existentes na minha Activity...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... e apago até o último caracter, ou seja, quando eu apago o último número restante (no caso o **"1"**), o app para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o problema fosse resolvido de forma a tornar o número **0** um caracter obrigatório, ou seja, se não tem nada inserido pelo usuário, **apareça o número 0 no EditText** e também se tiver algo, e posteriormente for tudo apagado, **ele reapareça**, de forma que mesmo que o usuário tente apagar **esse número 0** ele permaneça firme e forte.

**Main01Activity:**

```
package genesysgeneration.ruleoftree;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main01Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et01, et02, et03;
    private TextView tv01;
    private long l01, l02, l03;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main01);

        l01=0;
        l02=0;
        l03=0;

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);

        et01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et01);
        et02=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et02);
        et03=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et03);

        addValuesLong();

    }

    private void addValuesLong(){

        et01.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                l01=Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString().trim());
                tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        et02.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                l02=Long.parseLong(et02.getText().toString().trim());
                tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        et03.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                l03=Long.parseLong(et03.getText().toString().trim());
                tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: cade seu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema, uma possível solução é criar uma condição para comparar o tamanho do  `CharSequence` e realizar qualquer procedimento se ele for maior que `0`. Veja:

```
if (s.length() > 0) {

    // realize o procedimento
}
```

Sendo assim, ficaria desta forma:

```
et01.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.length() > 0) {
            l01 = Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString().trim());
            tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01 * l02 * l03));
        } else {
            l01 = 0;
            et01.setHint("0");
            tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

**Obs.:** É necessário fazer a condição todos `EditText`'s que estão sendo usados para esse propósito.

Comment: @boneco-sinforoso funcionou certinho ai?

Comment: simsim, agora vou resolver a parada da textview ki nn tah exibindo numero quebrado, vlw aew!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de definir o texto para 0 quando estiver vazio, use hint para isso:

```
editText.setHint("0");
```

Agora quando obter o número, tem que verificar se é o zero virtual (sem entrada) ou um texto:

```
long valor;
String text = editText.getText().toString();
if (text.isEmpty()) {
    valor = 0.0f;
} else {
    valor = Long.parseLong(text);
}
```

Assim quando estiver vazio, aparecerá um 0 no fundo. Se precisar altere a cor do hint para ficar parecido com o texto de entrada.

Comment: Estou usando long em vez de double, só substituir neh?

Comment: Sim, use `long valor` e `Long.parseLong(text)`

Comment: coloco isso dentro do addTextChangedListener? pq fora o app continua parando de funcionar.

Comment: colokei dentro, fora, com e sem else, nada. tah dando tudo na mesma.

Comment: Sim, dentro do `addTextChangedListener`.